# state of 'atomic cross-chain trading' in 2016

Tags: network, script

Much of the information I've come across is a bit dated, 2 years or so.

For instance, [this other question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/32278/atomic-cross-chain-trading), [this thread on the forum](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=193281.0;all).

It seems like [Interledger](https://interledger.org/interledger.pdf) is trying to implement, more or less, [the described protocol of ATXC](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Atomic_cross-chain_trading), is that right?

Other than that are there any actionable implementations around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Interledger's protocol is not atomic swaps. Their model is not entirely trustless either.
2. There are actionable implementations like MercuryEx but not used because:
   a. transaction malleability fix is required
   b. discovery problems in a decentralized system

Comment: This might need an update now, since malleability is fixed.